# How is memory loaded from virtual memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, paging

I know that Operating systems usually keep `Page Tables` to map a chunk of virtual memory to a chunk of physical memory.

My question is, does the CPU load the whole chunk when it's loading a given byte?

lets say I have:
`ld %r0, 0x4(%r1)`

Assuming my page size is `4 KB`, does the the CPU load all 4KB at once or it manages to
Load only a byte given the offset properly?

Is the `page size` mandated by the hardware or configurable by software and the OS?

#### Edit:

Figured that `page size` is mandated by hardware:

> The available page sizes depend on the instruction set architecture, processor type, and operating (addressing) mode. The operating system selects one or more sizes from the sizes supported by the architecture

Answer (score 0):

your question touches so many levels of cpu/memory architecture ... without knowing the exact cpu-architecture/memory-architecture/version you have in mind: while the cpu-command targets only one byte, it will trigger the memory-controller to locate the whole physical-page and load that one (atleast, prefetch might kick in) completely to second/first-level cache. your data is transfered after filling the cache.

Answer (score 0):

On a typical modern CPU, yes, it loads the whole page.

It couldn't really work any other way, since there are only two states in the page tables for a given page: present and not present.  If the page is present, it must be mapped to some page in physical memory.  If not present, every access to that page produces a page fault.  There is no "partially present" state.

In order for it to be safe for the OS to mark the page present, it has to load the entire page into physical memory and update the page tables to point the virtual page to the physical page.  If it only loaded a single byte or a smaller amount, the application might later try to access some other byte on the same page that hadn't been loaded, and it'd read garbage.  There's no way for the CPU to generate another page fault in that case to let the OS fix things up, unless the page were marked not present, in which case the original access wouldn't be able to complete either.

The page size is fixed in hardware, though some architectures offer a few different choices that the OS can select from.  For instance, recent x86-64 CPUs allow pages to be either 4 KB, 2 MB or 1 GB.  The OS can mix-and-match these at runtime; there are bits in the page tables to indicate the size of each page.

Comment: So data is also loaded into memory from hard disk is pages as well correct? Now 2 more question. How does `chad line` come into the picture here? I thought CPU also fetches data from memory according how big it's cache line is. Second question is, how does it store the data back into memory? according to page size again?

Comment: Edit, found the answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/270192/

Comment: @Dan: My answer is about how the page is loaded from disk into main memory.  You're correct that all or part of the page may also be in one or more levels of cache memory, but that is purely a hardware matter and the OS typically has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Dan: If the OS wishes to "swap out" the page by writing it to disk and evicting it from physical memory, it again has to write out the entire page and mark it as not present in the page table.   Then it can use the page of physical memory for something else.  If the page has not been modified since it was read in (the hardware would set a "dirty" bit if it were), then the write can be skipped.